# How to import nativescript pro ui modules to individual nativescript angular components without modules?

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

My problem is I need to import individual pro ui modules to components like lazy loading modules. However component generated by nativescript-cli doesn't have component.module.ts file.

Also note that global import of pro-ui modules are not working.

Answer (score 0):

For the best practice of how to import and use the {N} Pro UI modules in {N} + Angular application, I suggest you to take a look at the sdkAngular repository [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular) which is constantly being updated by the NativeScript team. That repository is using lazy loading for each component and app example.

On to your immediately question, if the nativescript-cli is not generating those for you maybe you want to use a different approach than the generic CLI is generating. Have you tried to manually create each component's module, the way you would do if you were developing a web Angular app? If you do that you can simply import each separate module from the {N} Pro UI like shown [here](https://github.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples-angular/blob/release/sdkAngular/app/listview/listview-examples.module.ts).